# como deixar imagem retangular?

Tags: html, css, imagem

Gostaria de saber como faço pra deixar uma imagem de notícia por exemplo no formato retangular, sem perder proporção. Procurei na internet e não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que a imagem esta retangular.

Comment: Do que se trata, de um recorte? Teria um exemplo?

Comment: editei a pergunta e coloquei uma imagem de exemplo.

Comment: Então, basicamente, você possui uma imagem de um forma específica e quer apresentá-la de forma retangular na página? É isso?

Comment: Exato Samir Braga!

Comment: O que você irá aparar a imagem, isto é aceitável pra ti?

Comment: Nesse formato já é o ideal praticamente. Em média a imagem original tem 600x400px

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que tenha muitas maneiras de se fazer isto por exemplo o `background-size` com `background-position`, como já citado.

No entanto `background-size` **não é suportado** por *alguns* navegadores mais antigos (se houver necessidade de controlar o tamanho), se tiver a necessidade de rodar em alguns mobiles mais antigos recomendo usar `overflow: hidden;`, veja um exemplo:

```css
.post .photo {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;

    /*Aqui deve ficar a altura da imagem desejada*/
    height: 150px;
}
.post .photo img {
    /*Aqui você deve ajustar pra centralizar a imagem verticalmente*/
    margin-top: -75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCKkG.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Veja a imagem original:

[image: logo]

Answer (score 1):

Bem Alexsander, isso pode ser feito de uma maneira bem simples, por meio da propriedade `background` do `css`. Por exemplo:

```
<div class="noticia"></div>
<style>
.noticia{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://goo.gl/n7nehC') no-repeat;

}
</style>
```

Resulta em: http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/qe7BJ/2/

Utilizando sua imagem como o background da `div`.
Através do `background-position` e do `background-size`, você poderá alterar a posição e o tamanho da imagem.

Há mais informações nesse documentos (em inglês):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: Teria como utilizar sem ser por background? pois a imagem está em banco de dados

Comment: @AlexsanderDuques pode usar a propriedade `style="background-image: url(<?php echo $row['image']?>)"`

Comment: A imagem estar no banco de dados não é empecilho.

Comment: Agradeço a todos pela atenção, vou testar aqui e dou retorno. Obrigado.